# Which modules help with loading of large images in a nice transition?

Tags: 7, media, performance

Currently I am using the single_page module that does the anchor page sliding thing on the page, but currently I'm loading big images onto this single page. Which modules or recommendations on how to streamline the loading of these large image files? I tried the image_lazyloader module but none of the images show up when activating this on the single_page module. I'm guessing these two modules have a conflict. What other possible options do i have? it seems that spotify.com has the same setup, how are they doing it there?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JAIL](https://drupal.org/project/jail). You will also need the jquery jail plugin.